# If x is a negative number, which one of those numbers are the bigger?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Those below are the only answers which I am having a hard time to find a solution:

A.6+x

B.6x

C.6/x

D.6-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, lets go throught the options.

A) 6+x. If x is a negative number, this will increase its value by 6, bringing it closer to or above 0.

B) 6x. Multiplying any negative number by a positive number will result in an even larger negative number, ruling this option out.

C) 6/x. Dividing a negative number by a positive number will always give a positive number, so this can also be ruled out.

D) 6-x. This is the correct answer. As subtracting a negative number will, essentially, be addition, this value will exceed the value achieved in option A.

Hope this helped!

Comment: option C) ?????

Answer (score 1):

B and C are negative and A is less than 6. D is greater than 6.